# Android: How to invoke keypad on second device on touch of first device?

Tags: android, webview, android-keypad, android-input-method

I have 2 android apps running on two different devices, both are communicating to each other through Bluetooth.

In first device am opening a webview which contains some input text fields. When i click on a text field of first device, I need to invoke keypad on second device.

How can i get trigger event when i touch input field?

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with bluetooth api. But on click of your input field send some identifier to the other device. When other device gets that identifier execute this code. Hope this works for you.

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```